# Breakout game, paddle moves all the way to the left when not pressing the controller gampad button

Tags: python, pygame, gamepad

I can't figure out why the paddle moves on its own all they way to the left when I run the game.

The gamepad controller does work and it moves the paddle but when your not pushing down on the gamepad controller ether left or right the paddle goes all the way back to the left wall.

This is not my code I just modified it so I can use a game pad.Below is a link to Code with Giovanni's Github page where I got the code.

https://github.com/codegiovanni/Breakout

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WIDTH = 893
HEIGHT = 1000
size = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Breakout 1976")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (212, 210, 212)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 97, 148)

RED = (162, 8, 0)
ORANGE = (183, 119, 0)
GREEN = (0, 127, 33)
YELLOW = (197, 199, 37)

score = 0
balls = 1
velocity = 4

paddle_width = 65
paddle_height = 20

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Controller

if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()


brick_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/brick.wav')
paddle_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/paddle.wav')
wall_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/wall.wav')


class Brick(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
        if self.rect.x > WIDTH - wall_width - paddle_width:
            self.rect.x = WIDTH - wall_width - paddle_width

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
        if self.rect.x < wall_width:
            self.rect.x = wall_width


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.velocity = [velocity, velocity]

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.rect.y += self.velocity[1]

    def bounce(self):
        self.velocity[0] = self.velocity[0]
        self.velocity[1] = -self.velocity[1]


paddle = Paddle(BLUE, paddle_width, paddle_height)
paddle.rect.x = WIDTH // 2 - paddle_width // 2
paddle.rect.y = HEIGHT - 65

ball = Ball(WHITE, 10, 10)
ball.rect.x = WIDTH // 2 - 5
ball.rect.y = HEIGHT // 2 - 5

all_bricks = pygame.sprite.Group()

brick_width = 55
brick_height = 16
x_gap = 7
y_gap = 5
wall_width = 16


def bricks():
    for j in range(8):
        for i in range(14):
            if j < 2:
                if i == 0:
                    brick = Brick(RED, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
                else:
                    brick = Brick(RED, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width + brick_width + x_gap + (i - 1) * (brick_width + x_gap)
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
            if 1 < j < 4:
                if i == 0:
                    brick = Brick(ORANGE, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
                else:
                    brick = Brick(ORANGE, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width + brick_width + x_gap + (i - 1) * (brick_width + x_gap)
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
            if 3 < j < 6:
                if i == 0:
                    brick = Brick(GREEN, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
                else:
                    brick = Brick(GREEN, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width + brick_width + x_gap + (i - 1) * (brick_width + x_gap)
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
            if 5 < j < 8:
                if i == 0:
                    brick = Brick(YELLOW, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)
                else:
                    brick = Brick(YELLOW, brick_width, brick_height)
                    brick.rect.x = wall_width + brick_width + x_gap + (i - 1) * (brick_width + x_gap)
                    brick.rect.y = 215 + j * (y_gap + brick_height)
                    all_sprites_list.add(brick)
                    all_bricks.add(brick)


brick_wall = bricks()

all_sprites_list.add(paddle)
all_sprites_list.add(ball)


def main(score, balls):

    step = 0

    run = True
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

###### GAME PAD CONTROLLER ############

        axis_x = (joystick.get_axis(0))
        if  abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
            paddle.moveRight(10)
        if  abs(axis_x) < 0.1:
            paddle.moveLeft(10)      

        all_sprites_list.update()

        if ball.rect.y < 40:
            ball.velocity[1] = -ball.velocity[1]
            wall_sound.play()

        if ball.rect.x >= WIDTH - wall_width - 10:
            ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
            wall_sound.play()

        if ball.rect.x <= wall_width:
            ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
            wall_sound.play()

        if ball.rect.y > HEIGHT:
            ball.rect.x = WIDTH // 2 - 5
            ball.rect.y = HEIGHT // 2 - 5
            ball.velocity[1] = ball.velocity[1]
            balls += 1
            if balls == 4:
                font = pygame.font.Font('text_style/DSEG14Classic-Bold.ttf', 50)
                text = font.render("GAME OVER", 1, WHITE)
                text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))
                screen.blit(text, text_rect)
                pygame.display.update()
                pygame.time.wait(2000)
                run = False

        if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, paddle):
            ball.rect.x += ball.velocity[0]
            ball.rect.y -= ball.velocity[1]
            ball.bounce()
            paddle_sound.play()

        brick_collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, all_bricks, False)
        for brick in brick_collision_list:
            ball.bounce()
            brick_sound.play()
            if len(brick_collision_list) > 0:
                step += 1
                for i in range(0, 448, 28):
                    if step == i:
                        ball.velocity[0] += 1
                        ball.velocity[1] += 1
            if 380.5 > brick.rect.y > 338.5:
                score += 1
                brick.kill()
            elif 338.5 > brick.rect.y > 294:
                score += 3
                brick.kill()
            elif 294 > brick.rect.y > 254.5:
                score += 5
                brick.kill()
            else:
                score += 7
                brick.kill()
            if len(all_bricks) == 0:
                font = pygame.font.Font('text_style/DSEG14Classic-Bold.ttf', 50)
                text = font.render("SCREEN CLEARED", 1, WHITE)
                text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))
                all_sprites_list.add(ball)
                screen.blit(text, text_rect)
                pygame.display.update()
                pygame.time.wait(2000)
                run = False

        screen.fill(BLACK)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREY, [0, 19], [WIDTH, 19], 40)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREY, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 0], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREY, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 0], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT], wall_width)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT - 65 + paddle_height / 2 - 54 / 2], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT - 65 + paddle_height / 2 - 54 / 2 + 54], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT - 65 + paddle_height / 2 - 54 / 2], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, HEIGHT - 65 + paddle_height / 2 - 54 / 2 + 54], wall_width)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 2 * brick_height + 2 * y_gap], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 2 * brick_height + 2 * y_gap], wall_width)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, ORANGE, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 2 * brick_height + 2 * y_gap], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 4 * brick_height + 4 * y_gap], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, ORANGE, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 2 * brick_height + 2 * y_gap], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 4 * brick_height + 4 * y_gap], wall_width)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 4 * brick_height + 4 * y_gap], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 6 * brick_height + 6 * y_gap], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, GREEN, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 4 * brick_height + 4 * y_gap], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 6 * brick_height + 6 * y_gap], wall_width)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, YELLOW, [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 6 * brick_height + 6 * y_gap], [(wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 8 * brick_height + 8 * y_gap], wall_width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, YELLOW, [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 6 * brick_height + 6 * y_gap], [(WIDTH - wall_width / 2) - 1, 212.5 + 8 * brick_height + 8 * y_gap], wall_width)

        font = pygame.font.Font('text_style/DSEG14Classic-Bold.ttf', 70)
        text = font.render(str(f"{score:03}"), 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(text, (80, 120))
        text = font.render(str(balls), 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(text, (520, 41))
        text = font.render('000', 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(text, (580, 120))
        text = font.render('1', 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(text, (20, 40))

        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()


main(score, balls)
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention I'm not a programmer, But I have spent a lot of time reading on how to use a controller in pygam because I really like this old childhood game.

Comment: I alredy ran the calibration but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the absolute value of the axis. The absolute value is always positive and if you don't move the stick at all, `abs(axis_x)` will always be < 0. The correct code would be:

```py
axis_x = joystick.get_axis(0)
if axis_x > 0.1:
    paddle.moveRight(10)
if axis_x < -0.1:
    paddle.moveLeft(10)
```

---

However, I suggest to implement dynamic movement instead of constant movement:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
        self.rect.x = max(wall_width, min(WIDTH - wall_width - paddle_width, self.rect.x))
```

```py
axis_x = joystick.get_axis(0)
if abs(axis_x) > 0.1:
    paddle.move(round(axis_x * 10))
```